# Does mediawiki allow me to make www.site.com/wiki/ the "main page" of the wiki?

Tags: mediawiki

...I know how to establish short URLs (using .htaccess) that remove the "index.php" from URLs. Now my Wiki main page URL looks like `www.site.com/wiki/Main_page`. However, i want it to simply look like `www.site.com/wiki/` . Is it possible to do this without heavy modifications to the source code?

Comment: Hardly, it still needs a page name. However, you can easily configure your server (not related to MediaWiki, though) to show `/Main_page` when visiting just `/wiki`

Comment: Hey @Bergi can you elaborate a little bit? Are you talking about `mod_rewrite` ? Anyway, I actually was able to hack away at the `Wiki.php` and come up with a solution, but maybe an Apache tweak would be better

Comment: Yup, when you're using Apache then that would probably the way.

Comment: I think it's not possible with `mod_rewrite` because MW check for what path is loaded and redirects to `/wiki/Main_page`. MW does not determine only `/wiki` (without slash); `/` and `/wiki/` are determined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done now. The main trick is to tell MediaWiki what the canonical URL of your main page is. To have the main page in the domain root:

```
$wgHooks['GetLocalURL'][] = function ( &$title, &$url, $query ) {
    if ( $title->isExternal() || $query != '' && $title->isMainPage() ) {
        $url = '/';
    }
};
```

See http://laxstrom.name/blag/2015/08/31/mediawiki-short-urls-with-nginx-and-main-page-without-redirect/ for full details.

Comment: Thanks @Nemo , I put that code at the end of my `LocalSettings.php`, and I adjusted `$url` to be `/wiki/` (because that's where I want my Wiki to be, *not* the root of domain), and it sorta seemed to work. But then I tried to click the "Edit" button in the top-right, and realized that the link was "hardcoded" to go to `site.com/wiki` instead of what it used to go to (*should* go to..) `site.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Main_Page&action=edit` .... so even though that code you gave helps some, it doesn't seem to be the complete solution I need for my situation.